# Trying to export a list of dictionary values given an xls file with a list of keys

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

Very new to Python, apologies if this question is obvious but I've been struggling for awhile.

I created a dictionary from one Excel file using this code, and I wrote it out to a CSV file just to make sure the dictionary was what I expected:

```py
import pandas as pd
    import csv
    dictionary = pd.read_excel('excel_file.xlsx', index_col=0).to_dict()
    with open('dict.csv', 'w') as csv_file:  
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            writer.writerow([key, value])
```

What I'm trying to do now is that I have a second file, an extremely long list of keys, also as an Excel file. All of the keys in the second file are defined in the dictionary, it just has a lot of duplicates.

I want to feed that list into the dictionary and have it write out a new xls file where the second column contains a value for each key from the aforementioned list. I'm am completely stumped at this part, and would appreciate any advice to point me in the right direction. I tried something like this to even just see if I could print the results to the console, and it didn't work:

```py
keylist = pd.read_excel('keys.xlsx', index_col=0).to_dict()
print([dictionary[x] for x in keylist])
```